# How to directly retrieve a UTC OffsetDateTime using MySQL Connector/J?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, offsetdatetime

I prefer all times to be in UTC, except for when they are displayed.  At the last moment, they can be converted to a local time for display only.

I've always stored UNIX timestamps (seconds since epoch) in MySQL before, in an integer field. I'm working with someone else's database schema that I cannot change which uses a `DATETIME` that stores a raw time without even an offset.

How can I retrieve and send time objects with the database in UTC, so the database is doing absolutely no conversions whatsoever?

---

Although written for PostgreSQL, I've tried to follow the excellent answers by Basil Bourque on the questions below.  I use `Instant` everywhere, except as he shows I use an `OffsetDateTime` when interacting with JDBC, because it's the only modern moment class guaranteed to be supported by JDBC 4.2.

- [How to convert UTC date to UTC OffsetDateTime in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326102/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-utc-offsetdatetime-in-java-8)
- [Issue in saving current date with UTC time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099500/issue-in-saving-current-date-with-utc-time-in-sql-server)
- and [How to save correct date time with timezone when using jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676450/how-to-save-correct-date-time-with-timezone-when-using-jdbc)

I'm using MySQL Connector/J driver version 8.0.27, and I am connecting with `&preserveInstants=false&connectionTimeZone=UTC`.

Let's look at a `DATETIME` in the database stored as "2022-01-14 11:00:00" which is understood to be UTC.

```
resultSet.getString(columnName); // "2022-01-14 11:00:00"
resultSet.getObject(columnName, OffsetDateTime.class).toString() // "2022-01-14T11:00-04:00"
resultSet.getObject(columnName, OffsetDateTime.class).toInstant().toString() // "2022-01-14T15:00:00Z"
```

When it's creating the `OffsetDateTime`, it's assigning either the system or server (same machine) offset of "-04:00" and messing everything up. I thought my connection options of `&preserveInstants=false&connectionTimeZone=UTC` should have stopped that.

I know I could immediately set the offset to "+00:00" afterward with `.withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()`, but how do I avoid doing that and have it directly create an `OffsetDateTime` that is in UTC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

You’ve pinpointed the core issue: The author of your table defined the column as a MySQL [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type. That type represents only a date with time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset. That MySQL `DATETIME` column is akin to the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

## `java.time.LocalDateTime`

So you are using the wrong Java class when retrieving a value from that `DATETIME` column. Rather than use `OffsetDateTime`, use `LocalDateTime`. Like `DATETIME` ( and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`), the Java type `LocalDateTime` represents a date with time-of-day but no zone or offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Determine a moment

You can the assign an offset or time zone to pinpoint a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

You said:

> it's assigning either the system or server (same machine) offset of "-04:00" and messing everything up.

Some part along the route of traversal is trying to help you along with your code’s intention of starting with a date and time only value that ends up with an offset assigned. Likely your JDBC driver is the part assigning an offset. Since no offset is stored with a MySQL `DATETIME`, *some* offset needs to be assigned in order to produce the `OffsetDateTime` object you requested.

As shown above, a better approach is to **not ask for a `OffsetDateTime`** object when using a database column lacking an offset.

You asked:

> How can I retrieve and send time objects with the database in UTC, so the database is doing absolutely no conversions whatsoever?

You cannot exchange a moment as seen in UTC with a database column lacking the concept of an offset-from-UTC.

If you want to represent moments in a SQL database, you must use the appropriate data type, a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

What you are asking for in exchanging a date-time-with-offset value with a database column that is date-time-only is like asking to store a price in Japanese Yen in a mere numeric column. You can *pretend* that such recorded values represent a price in Yen, but you do not know. Someone could just as well store prices in Euros or Pesos there.

Since you seem to be stuck in a pickle regarding your current work situation, you can *pretend* that your `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`  column stores UTC values. That is what my code example above does, essentially.

To pretend while writing values, adjust to UTC, then extract a `LocalDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ; 
LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

This pretending approach is fraught with peril, and irresponsible. The database is tracking a fiction, not the truth.  Be sure to document this hack, as any programmer new to the system would be thoroughly confused.

By the way, notice that the type names `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` are misnomers. From what I’ve been told, and from what I’ve seen in drafts, the SQL standard actually meant offsets only, not really time zones. That is why `OffsetDateTime` is the only Java class mapped in JDBC for matching to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.